# jQuery events wont execute after reapplying class selectors

Tags: jquery

Okay so I have a problem where I am using buttons on a custom form that execute two AJAX methods, Both these functions work when first selected in the correct fashion. The problem I'm having is after trying to execute the same function again after adding / removing classes that have the event handlers on them they fail to execute again meaning they only have a single life span and can't be used again.

From my research I have found that this problem is jQuery event delegation and after reading the documentation I changed my original click functions to on functions which should reapply the event handlers after the change from my understanding.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".checkButton").on('click', function () {
            var objID = this.id;
            $.ajax({
                url: "index.php?system=testimonials&task=update",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {val: objID},
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                {
                    $("#testimonialSpan" + objID).removeClass("label-warning");
                    $("#testimonialSpan" + objID).addClass("label-success");
                    $("#testimonialSpan" + objID).text("Approved");
                    $("#testimonialTick" + objID).removeClass("fa-check");
                    $("#testimonialTick" + objID).addClass("fa-times");
                    $("#" + objID).removeClass("checkButton");
                    $("#" + objID).addClass("timesButton");
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    alert(textStatus + errorThrown + jqXHR);
                }
            });
        });

        $(".timesButton").on('click', function () {
            var objID = this.id;
            $.ajax({
                url: "index.php?system=testimonials&task=update",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {times: objID},
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                {
                    $("#testimonialSpan" + objID).removeClass("label-success");
                    $("#testimonialSpan" + objID).addClass("label-warning");
                    $("#testimonialSpan" + objID).text("Pending");
                    $("#testimonialTick" + objID).removeClass("fa-times");
                    $("#testimonialTick" + objID).addClass("fa-check");
                    $("#" + objID).removeClass("timesButton");
                    $("#" + objID).addClass("checkButton");
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    alert(textStatus + errorThrown + jqXHR);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

I believe I am close but I have not been able to make this function as expected.

Comment: After moving away from delegated events and directly attaching the events they still only execute once? Or they do not execute at all now? What are you experiencing now that you are not delegating them? Direct event attachments don't get reapplied. They are directly attached to those elements. Changing the elements shouldn't affect the events unless you remove them from the DOM and even then you can tell jQuery to leave events attached if you plan on putting them back in. Event delegation attaches the event to an ancestor who then passes the event to the element(s) that match the selector.

Comment: I have possibly been reading the wrong documentation, There is no new element created, rather the current element has the class changed to have the opposite class inside of it. My previous understanding was that as long as that selector was present the correct method would fire.

Comment: Yes if the selector still matches it should still fire. You can stick with delegated events if you just choose a class that will not change. Since you can use multiple classes pick a class to use for delegation. Then use other classes to change things around just don't change the class you are using for delegation. Even still directly attaching the events like you are in the code above should work. I am still not sure what issue you are experiencing now.

Comment: http://puu.sh/piSTI/a164fd8486.png, Once I click the tick on this image it is changed in the back end and becomes approved. Using the above code it is then applied a new class that matches the second method. If I go to click the same button it will not change back to pending.

Comment: Look when directly attaching an event changing the class won't matter because its attached directly to the element. The only time the class matters is when you first select it to attach the event: https://jsfiddle.net/7ratuu0x/

Comment: I guess I am still trying to understand what you expect. Do you expect the button to call the same function every time its clicked? Or should the buttons be calling the other function when you switch their classes?

Comment: I appreciate the jsfiddle but this doesn't solve the issue I'm having the event still will not execute after being used once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `$(document).on('click', '.checkButton', function(){});` instead of `$(".checkButton").on('click', function(){});` and `$(document).on('click', '.timesButton ', function(){});` instead of `$(".timesButton").on('click', function () {});`

It binds event to the document not to the element. so whenever you click on element with the selector it fires.

Comment: Thank you Ravisha I knew I was missing something simple :-)